# Why doesn't this Python 2.7 Turtle code process penup?

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

Below is my code (it doesn't process the penup). What's wrong with this code? (Sorry about my bad English.)

```
import turtle

import time

t = turtle.Turtle()

wn = turtle.Screen()

t.ht()

t.pensize(6)

t.speed(0)

wn.title("Trivia")

class trivia():

    def __init__(self):

        self.BlueBtn()

    def Btn(self):
        t.begin_fill()
        for p in xrange(2):
            t.left(90)
            t.fd(170)
            t.lt(90)
            t.fd(470)
        t.end_fill()


    def BlueBtn(self):               #button a - the blue button
        t.penup()
        t.setx(-370)
        t.pendown()

        t.color("blue","aqua")   #make the button's color
        self.Btn()               #make the button
        self.RedBtn()

    def RedBtn(self):                #button b - the red button
        t.pu()
        t.setx(370)
        t.pd()
        t.color("darkred","red")   #make the button's color
        self.Btn()
        self.GreenBtn()

    def GrennBtn(self):               #button c - the green button
        t.pu()
        t.sety(-400)
        t.pd()

        t.color("darkgreen","green") #make the button's color
        self.Btn(self)                   #make the button
        self.GoldBtn()

    def GoldBtn(self):                #make button d - the gold button
        t.pu()
        t.setx(-370)
        t.pd()

        t.color("gold","khaki")   #make the button's color
        self.Btn()                #make the button


turtle.mainloop()                 #exit from the turtle screen while pressing on the cross

game = trivia()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to make the code section be easier to read. Use Ctrl+K to correctly indent the selected code section

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The major problem with this code is this sequence:

```
turtle.mainloop()
game = trivia()
```

When you invoke `mainloop()` you turn control over to the Tk event loop so it should be the last thing you do.  Commands after this don't get executed until turtle is being shut down.  So reverse it:

```
game = trivia()
turtle.mainloop()
```

There are also lots of little errors (e.g. `self.Btn(self)` passes two `self` arguments instead of one) which I've tried to address in a rewrite of your code that should run under Python 2 or 3:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, mainloop

class trivia():

    def __init__(self):
        self.BlueBtn((-550, 100))
        self.RedBtn((100, 100))
        self.GreenBtn((100, -250))
        self.GoldBtn((-550, -250))

    def Btn(self, position):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(position)
        turtle.pendown()

        turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(2):
            turtle.forward(450)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(150)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.end_fill()

    def BlueBtn(self, position):  # button a - the blue button
        turtle.color('blue', 'cyan')  # I don't have 'aqua'
        self.Btn(position)

    def RedBtn(self, position):  # button b - the red button
        turtle.color('darkred', 'red')
        self.Btn(position)

    def GreenBtn(self, position):  # button c - the green button
        turtle.color('darkgreen', 'green')
        self.Btn(position)

    def GoldBtn(self, position):  # make button d - the gold button
        turtle.color('gold', 'khaki')
        self.Btn(position)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 600)
screen.title('Trivia')

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.pensize(6)

game = trivia()

mainloop()  # exit from the turtle screen by pressing on the cross
```